# How to redesign use of Elastic search Scroll API, because of memory limits

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-batch, batch-processing, rx-java

I have a restriction on memory that my application uses.

I'm generating files consisting of data returned from Elastic Search.

As I need to get all the data that stored in ES I'm using [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html) to get data and that put it to some `Collection<Foo>`. For now ES contains about several thousands records of `Foo` that is returned.

So it is more like imperative approach, because i'm loading all data like:

```
List<Foo> allFoos = FooSource.loadAllFoo();
```

And then do some processing, after which I'm saving results to different files.

Then this files are accessible from REST endpoint.

So what I'm looking for is some advice how to limit memory usage that this approach rises.

I was thinking of instead of putting all the data in memory and then operate on it do some sequential processing as the data comes available.

Do I need some Java Rx or Spring Batch technology in this case ? It helped me if you produce some code samples or even pseudo code will be alright.

Comment: It looks like you need Apache Camel or Spring Integration

Comment: You can combine ES with Spring Batch to enable batch processing in chunks instead of processing all at once. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-elasticsearch